# Automatically perform javascript function on pageload of external website

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

So I want to have a link to a site x (which I am not the developer of) that automatically performs some javascript function after it is clicked. EG.

```
javascript:window.location="http://www.google.com"; alert("Hello");
```

This performs the alert function before loading the page which is *not* desired.

Does anyone else know how *this* can be achieved?

Thanks.

Comment: You cant execute javascript on a page that you link to ...

Comment: you can make a external JS by <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that.

Doing this, poses a security threat (XSS), and therefore disallowed by almost all the browsers!!

Worst scenarios to think of, if you had this control:

- The Script to capture the username/pass of the user and mail it to you by further calling an Url.
- Could play a role in unwarranted tracking/spamming.

**EDIT:**

This can be done only if user interaction in involved.

For eg:

- You can ask user to drag a link to his bookmark toolbar, and the link should contain:

  `<a href="javascript:alert('click');">Test Click</a>`
- And then to whatever page the user goes, whenever he clicks the bookmark button (link), an alert happens (or whatever script you may put.)

Comment: can you give me the name of a browser that allows that? (since you write "almost all")

Comment: @MichalB.: Since I haven't tested all browsers of world myself and the ones which you and me could create to allow this, I preferred putting the world almost-all rather than all!! And you are downvoting my answer for this?

Comment: To me it seems like being not sure, therefore using safe words. Also those exclamation marks are not necessary. Cheers

Comment: @MichalB.: whatever it may seem to you, I gave a clear reason for my word usage (like your or mine or any future browser may support it)! What is necessary and whats not, is my choice, you can have your own answer right?

Answer (score 1):

If you load it in an iframe, I guess you could somehow wait for a certain element to be present and then execute your code.

Comment: That's another option. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the link is changing the "current" windows location, you cant execute your scripts after the external page has started loading.

Comment: so what am I supposed to do then?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

A walk around way is to put the site in to an iframe in your page. Then alert your message in its onload event. And of course your url on address bar will not change.